# Get the drop down items in the console in React js

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I need to fetch the clicked dropdown item and  log it in the console using React js.

Code:

```
<div onClick={this.handleSearchBtn} className="dropdown-menu">
  <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#" >Authors</a>
  <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">Article Title</a>
  <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">PMID</a>
  <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">Mesh Terms</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried till now? And what doesn't work?

Comment: i need to add the functionality in handleSearchBtn()  using document.getElementsByClassName('search-item') i will get all the items  but I need to get the  clicked items

Comment: For example, you have clicked the `PMID` and `Authors` and when you click on the handleSearchBtn, you need to get `PMID, Authors`, right?

Comment: Yes like a radio btn only one selection can be made and it should be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you can do something like this

```js
class Anchor extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: ''
  }

  handleSearchBtn = (event) => {
    if (event.target.className.indexOf("search-item") !== -1) {
      this.setState({ selected: event.target.text });
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleSearchBtn} className="dropdown-menu">
        selected: {this.state.selected}
        <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">
          Authors
        </a>
        <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">
          Article Title
        </a>
        <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">
          PMID
        </a>
        <a className="search-item dropdown-item" href="#">
          Mesh Terms
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Anchor />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZXYaX?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it works!! great ... I cant understand
 event.target.className.indexOf("search-item") !== -1
Could you explain

Comment: @Rennie I am checking whether the clicked element is an anchor or not. For that, I am using `event.target.className.indexOf("search-item") !== -1` since all the anchor tag has the class `search-item`